# Как правильно пишется слово совмешяя

Tags: выбор-слов

Как правильно написать слово совмесшяя

Comment: Вы бы хоть предложение написали целиком. А то трудно даже представить, какое слово можно так изуродовать. *совместная?* *совмещая?*

Answer (score 1):

[**Совмеща́я**](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) — это деепричастие (что делая?) от глагола "совмещать".

В словаре Ефремовой:
**совмеща́ть**, *несов. перех.*

1. Соединять, сочетать.
   *отт.* Обладать несколькими чертами, качествами, свойствами.
2. Выполнять одновременно.
3. Делать совпадающими при наложении друг на друга (*линии, фигуры и т. п.*).
4. *устар.* Заключать в себе.

*Проминая в резиновых перчатках живот больного и **совмещая** с его криками «больно» слепые расплывчатые зашифрованные оттенки пятен и теней...* (А. И. Солженицын)

*Низ колонн выверяют, **совмещая** риски, обозначающие их геометрические оси в нижнем сечении, с рисками разбивочных осей или...* (Ю. Н. Казаков)

*Сокращая затраты времени на отдельные операции или **совмещая** несколько операций, машинист при определенном опыте работы может...* (А. И. Астахов)